# ERROR Attempt to access MessageEventPage with unverified url: /sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx error when clicking on Unsubscribe link

Tags: exm

I'm using EXM 3.5 and when I click on Unsubscribe link `(/sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx)` I got an error:

> ERROR Attempt to access MessageEventPage with unverified url: /sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx
>
> INFO  Cannot handle unsubscription event. No message id was provided in the request
>
> 6024 10:41:28 ERROR Failed to process an email opened task

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open that page directly from email campaign when you are authoring message body if this is what you were trying to do.
Without additional parameters in query string it won't work. Parameters are added to query string during message generation before send out.

You should try to send email to your test contact and you will see.

You should have there message id, contact id ("ec" as far as I remember) and other parameters in query string.

Here is exact location where exception is thrown for you:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the url that generated in exm is http://mysite.com/sitecore modules/Web/EXM/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=JsmqDk5v7tZNx0SCbNTZT551pUE7peMsnBwvYz7ArDgHHPROHynatKJ9M2J24rrDT%2beTDguYm%2bSNBd2iaGRQkqDdh7SKcdbHK4Udg6KlOmjdDGqxQ4YffX1rkBeZptNYXFnx%2fiBLuAMKqi27aK%2fU8dH9zKNir07uqv3V5FW5NenerXxP5g1uGTFTmXayl3Kw0cknYUfWNLETHlWxiL3Ckm4sQ2FsSnqs0AVXIDpMSjVVfjGEDPOhWWz4XgD7Hj64CSoUPNf4M%2bwEnBKqpRTQxDGdKiMUk3AEwV%2bId3aulTyp4TO975PXkE6RaQ60mJz%2byErAryfz2bO8xtYN9cJ8We%2bFdd%2bQIdaK0eWQG8Rkw39sk8PUOiLRJ4f2MrHJHEJt

Comment: And if you open url from your previous comment, you receive exception or now it's ok?

Comment: when I click the link, send to the homepage, and I didn't receive the unsubscribe email. After that I checked on the logs and show those messages :  INFO Cannot handle unsubscription event. No message id was provided in the request

10:41:28 ERROR Failed to process an email opened task

Comment: Do you have Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check crypto keys in your config on CD and CM servers whether they are not different? They should be the same.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. The subscription confirmation and notification email are right, it's just missing the unsubscribe. the email html link is /sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx. is it right?

Comment: You can debug by placing a processor in the <redirectUrl> pupeline that logs the query string params and theirnl values after decryption of ec_eq parameter.